# Return a random object from a list based on proprieties

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

This is quite a strange issue for me because I can't visualize my problem correctly. Just so that you know, I'm not really asking for code but just for **an idea to write an approriate alogirthm** that would generate some weather based on their probability of occuring.

Here's what I want to achieve :

Let's say I have a **WeatherClass**, with a parameter called "**Probability**". I want to have different weather instances with their own probability of "happening".

```
enum Probability {
Never = -1,
Low = 0,
Normal = 1,
Always = 2
};

std::vector<WeatherClass> WeatherContainer;

WeatherClass Sunny = WeatherClass();
Sunny.Probability = Probability.Normal;

WeatherClass Rainy = WeatherClass();
Rainy.Probability = Probability.Low;

WeatherClass Cloudy = WeatherClass();
Cloudy.Probability = Probability.Normal;

WeatherContainer.push_back(Sunny);
WeatherContainer.push_back(Rainy);
WeatherContainer.push_back(Cloudy);
```

Now, my question is : what is the most clever way to return some weather based on its own probability of happening?

I don't know why but I can't figure this out.. My first guess would be to have some kind of "luck" variable and compare it with the probability of each element or something similar.

Any hint or advice would be really helpful.

Greets,

required

Comment: "Always" and "Never" will ruin your probability scheme. If it's always sunny, it won't be rainy.  If it's never sunny, you may as well not have such a class.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention why I inserted those into the enum, 'Always' and 'Never' were used for debugging purposes, it was used to override the probability and immediately execute the first weather with that parameter.

Comment: You need to figure out the logic of when to pick one above the other yourself and tell us how you want it to work and then we can help with the code. Everyone just throwing in their opinion of how they think it should work is not really what [so] is about.

Comment: Lookup std::discrete_distribution, It covers your case precisely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking, assuming you have an integer sequence of numbers representing a linear increase in probability (starting from 1, not 0!):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6...n
```

Marking `pn` for some specific integer (weather in your scheme, say "6"), and the sum of all the enum integers `Sn`, a linear probability could easily be defined as:

```
pn/Sn
```

This of course means the weather associated with "1" is least likely, and the one with "n" is most likely. Other schemes are possible, such as exponential - just need to normalize properly. Also, if you forgot your math:

```
Sn=(1+n)*n/2
```

Now you need to roll from this probability. One option, disregarding efficiency, to help you think about this:

Make a giant set, where each weather (or integer) appears as many times as the associated integer. 1 appears once, ..., n appears n times. This list is of size `Sn` by definition. Now use the random library:

```
int choice = rand() % Sn; #index between 0 and Sn-1 - chosen probability indicator.
```

You could of course randomize the list as well for extra randomness.

An example: in our array we have `probmap={1,2,2,3,3,3}`. If `choice==4`, then `probmap[4]==3`. Suppose 3 corresponds to `Sunny`, then we have our result!. There are of course ways to make this better, choose different probability functions etc. but I think this is a good start.

Comment: Wow I thought pressing ENTER while writing a comment would have created a new line but it posted prematurely my answer.. so here's the complete comment :

First of all thanks for your complete explaination. I really couldn't think of something like this. There is just one thing I don't get : "Marking pn for some specific integer". What did you exactly mean?

Here's also a result of the code in action :
http://i.imgur.com/BBNHM95.png

Comment: @required You marked integers as probabilities 1 - least probable, 2 -more probable, etc until n - most probable. So `Pn` is one of these to keep things mathematical and general. As an example say you take the weather associated with integer 6, so `pn=6` and the probability would be `6/(1+2+3+4+5+6+7....+n)`. Also, please up-vote to negate the nice guy/girl down voting across the board.

Answer (score -2):

You can generate a random number between 0 and 3, subtract 1, cast it to Probability and search your vector for a matching entry.

```
auto result = rand();
result %= 4;
--result;
auto prob = (Probability)result;
auto index = -1;
for( auto I = 0 ; I < WeatherContainer.size() ; ++I )
   if( WeatherContainer [ I ].Probability == prob )
   {
        index = I;
        break;
   }

if( index != -1 )
{
     // Do your thing
}
```